# What's the extent should one practice defensive programming?

Tags: coding-style

What's the extent should one practice defensive programming?

I have this code which is a bit defensive, so in case someone swapped the left and right expression of OR statement, the code would still work:

```
&& ( companyId == Guid.Empty 
     || (companyId != Guid.Empty && x.StoreCompany.CompanyId == companyId) )
```

Would you boot me out of your organization if I re-factor that and shortened it to:

```
&& (companyId == Guid.Empty || x.StoreCompany.CompanyId == companyId)
```

Comment: I think if a company booted you for this change, then you might not want to be at the company.

Comment: I'm just thinking of IT shops in general, I want to mesh well with general practices of most companies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shorter/less confusing logical statements are, the better. I'd commend you for doing such a refactor.

Answer (score 3):

Of course I wouldn't boot you. Rather, I'd expect developers to understand the consequences of moving things around as you've described. How would swapping the left and right expressions of that OR statement change things?

Comment: +1 to you and Loren. Yeah, you are right, the second code would still work even they are swapped, it's a very contrived example. Anyway, nevermind, I will opt for simplicity, I will remove the `companyId != Guid.Empty` as Loren Pechtel also advised. However this is what I'm really thinking of, where order matters, is more along this kind of code: `if( p.Country == null || p.Country.CountryId == countryId)`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not seeing what you think is the problem with your proposed refactor.

In the original the companyId != Guid.Empty is always true and thus meaningless.  Why not remove it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably have unkind words if you used the first version in production. What you've posted isn't defensive coding, it's redundant coding.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler probably removes the additional check in the first example in any case, it achieves nothing. You did the right thing, short of slapping the person who wrote the original statement.

HOWEVER!!!

Looking at it algebraically your re factor is invalid I think.

P + (!P.Q) <> P + Q

Your saving grace is the function does not need to be bi linear. Practically though it is more likely the original statement was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really defensive programming. DP, as embodied especially in the classic 90s McConnell tome *Code Complete* is really about incrementally accumulating buttresses in the code that are informed by usage. So you start with some basic assertions and then as you see things getting through the screen, you add more.

Personally, I tend toward the Bertrand Meyer side of this spectrum: contracts. Whether you can really achieve the 'proof' levels he aspires to has been much debated, but his screeds against defensive programming are brilliant. The net net is any system that doesn't know how it can fail until a user has shown it is a work of madness. A component should do one thing only, and prescribe exactly what it needs to do it (in preconditions) and guarantee the result (post) given that nothing else goes sideways in the course of it (invariants).